# Vue js add animate for element when route page

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2

I just want to animate specific element when route page load complete. its not route page transition. i have tried many ways. its a progress bar animate percentage of dynamicly from data value. i have tried mount destroyed method for change class but its not working.
my requirement is i want to pass value from data and according to the value, the progress bar shour be animate when page load.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwfvc.png)

```
<div class="media-body">
     <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" v-bind:class="{rating: isAnimate}">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

```css
  .mybar {
    height: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #C1C2C1;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .myactivebar {
    background-color: #B01058;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: width 1s ease;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
}
.rating {
  width:100%;
}
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      isAnimate: false,
      technologies:[
        {
          title:'Vue Js',
          info:'progressive framework for building user interfaces.',
          logo:'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png',
          rate:90
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html Guards get triggered on each navigation. You could use a `.beforeEach` for showing the bar and `.afterEach` for filling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually what I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owwKB.gif)

and I got the solution below

```css
@-moz-keyframes animate-bar {
    0%   { width: 0%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-bar {
    0%   { width: 0%; }
}

@-ms-keyframes animate-bar {
    0%   { width: 0%; }
}

@-o-keyframes animate-bar {
    0%   { width: 0%; }
}

@-keyframes animate-bar {
    0%   { width: 0%; }
}

.chart {
  background-color: #DADADA;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.chart .bar {
  background-color: #3D98C6;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
  -webkit-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
  -ms-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
  -o-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
  animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
   <div class="bar" style="width:60%;"></div>
</div>
```